# How can I neatly take washer waste around the downpipe?

Tags: drain, pipe

I'm in the process of improving the looks of the back of our house, and want to now sort out the mess of pipes going into the drain.  One of the pipes is a 40mm waste from the washing machine, and is on the "wrong" side of the main house downpipe.

Assuming cutting the downpipe and fitting it directly into it isn't an option (it's too big/risky of a job right now), what are my options for neatly taking it past?

[image]
[image]

As seen in the photos, right now it's just using two 90° bends to take it out far enough past the downpipe.  There's *just* enough space to force a 32mm pipe behind it against the wall, but it would have to be bent (ie put under stress) to allow for any fixings.  Ideally I'd like to take the pipe back around to join up with at least one of the other two wastepipes before they drop into the drain.

Is there such a thing as a pipe designed to fit around the outside of a downpipe for this sort of situation, or is my best option to stick with 90° bends to do the job, using solvent rather than screw ones to make it look nicer/less bulky?

Comment: It's a non-pressure line, why don't you try using a heat gun to carefully create a bend in a single piece of pipe. Warm it up and bend it around a suitably sized object away from the drain line, practice with a scrap piece.

Comment: @JimmyFix-it Nice idea - will have to see if I know anyone with a heat gun :)

Comment: If your very careful on keeping the temp low so as not to burn the pipe, you can heat it over a outdoor grill.  I prefer this for larger pipes over the heat-gun.

Comment: Some what depending on what the other two drains are used for there should be no reason not to "Y" join them together.  The pipes appear to both be ABS.   The Washer pipe looks to be PVC, and if a transition to ABS was added, it could also "Y" in.  Issues of concern merging to one output is how much total flow out of each pipe (can one handle total)  and  back flow.

Answer (score 1):

It probably should have been done using 45 degree elbows, in the first place, but honestly I think that it looks better the way it is than it would if you had a bent piece of pipe there. That would really look like a part-time fix. If it's not clogging, I'm really curious as to why you're wanting to make a change until you can directly run to sewer line.

Comment: We have a 2 year old who recently decided he likes playing in the drain - I'm going to put some sort of cover over the top of it, and while I'm at it want to tidy the pipe work up to look as well as it can.  Ideally I just want one pipe dropping through the cover, but if it has to be all 3, so be it.